# Ubuntu 14.04 screen becomes unreadable

Tags: screen

**Before lightdm installed:**

[image: Patchy Ubuntu 14.04 screen after some time]

When starting there is no issue, after some time the screen becomes like this. along with icons right and left click menus are also unable to read.

what to do?

The issue is in Ubuntu 14.04 
uname -a => ... 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP ... x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**After gdm (in which lightdm) installed:**

```
    [+0.02s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.10.1, UID=0 PID=5023
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Using Xephyr for X servers
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Registered seat module surfaceflinger
[+0.06s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
[+0.06s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting
[+0.06s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating greeter session
[+0.09s] DEBUG: Seat: Creating display server of type x
[+0.14s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.14s] DEBUG: Seat: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.14s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-1.log
[+0.15s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:1
[+0.15s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Launching X Server
[+0.17s] DEBUG: Launching process 5027: /usr/bin/Xephyr :1 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.17s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Waiting for ready signal from X server :1
[+0.17s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.17s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
```

[image]

Still problem persists,

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 10)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 01)
```

glxinfo | grep OpenGL:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G33 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 10.1.3
OpenGL extensions:
```

## > cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log|grep  WW

```
[    22.452] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    22.452] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    22.452] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    22.453] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    22.453] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    23.822] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    23.822] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    23.822] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
```

**Edit Aug-26-2014**

**CCSManager all effected disabled already.**

[image]

Comment: Upgrade your OS :
$ sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude full-upgrade
Could fix your issue..

Comment: Did you try to restart lightdm ?
What's your system Graphics? It's better to Copy your lightdm log, so we can help you.

Comment: gdm installed, lightdm log added. still issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

lightdm and gdm are just login greeters and they disappear after you login.
What you see here is a terminal on top of browser, i.e. a user session when lightm/gdm are already gone into background.
So lightdm/gdm have nothing to do with it, they still might trigger some bugs which corrupt memory and hence your experience afterwards, but the core problem is somewhere else.

It looks like a graphics artefact, in particular problematic window compositing (relying on 2D acceleration).
Most likely with compositor (user program running with your unity, like compiz -- thus you may try upgrading or trying a different version) or your graphics driver (try changing open source nouvou into proprietary nvidia or smth -- need to know what graphics card you have).

Or as a workaround you can try turning off some or all desktop effects (in particular window shadows).

Comment: glxinfo,lspci dumps added.

Comment: You have Intel video card with open-source drivers.
you can try looking at /var/log/xorg.0.log
especially lines with EE and WW.

Comment: WW lines added.any clue?

Comment: nope, those lines look normal: by default xorg is just probing different drivers.

Comment: @Kumar could you try disabling desktop visual effects and see if you still have problems? I'd like to rule out that it is not the fancy compositing library at fault.

Comment: Already all visual effects are removed. Pls see the attached ccsManager image.

Comment: issue still persists. How to reset screen without restart?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issues with my laptop before. I found that I could fix this by running the command `unity --replace` from command line (<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>). On my laptop this temporarily fixed the issue.